# How to use String.Format to show only cents and omit dollars

Tags: c#, wpf, decimal

I want to display only tenths of decimal.

```
decimal d = 44.22m;

var s = d.ToString("");
```

How to make this `s == "22"` true ?

PS: i'm well aware i can do some math but i'm want to display tenths in WPF using only Binding and `StringFormat`

Comment: Would it be ok to use a converter?

Comment: I really didnt want to complicate things but if there's no StringFormat available, i'll use a converter

Comment: I don't think that you get an answer which doesn't need to use maths and only needs `String.Format` or `ToString`. By the way, the question would be easier to understand if you'd use a title like _"How to use String.Format to show only cents and omit dollars"_

Comment: Agree, going with the converter

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I also dont think there is a pure -String.Format- way to get the cents.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best but it works :

```
        decimal d = 44.22m;
        string ds = d.ToString().Remove(0, (d.ToString().IndexOf(',') + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal d = 44.22m;

Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d*(?=m)");
Match match = regex.Match(d);
if (match.Success)
{
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a lot of operations, maybe set up a function for this step!? I guess using `String.Format` only wouldnt work.

```
int getDecimals (decimal d)
{
    try
    {
        int s = Convert.ToInt32(string.Format("{0}", d.ToString().Split('.')[1]));
        return s;
    }
    catch { //whatever u want// }
}

// ==> //

decimal d = 44.22m;

string s = getDecimals(d).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer posted for a similar question here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19374418/4101237

posted by user
https://stackoverflow.com/users/2608383/karthik-krishna-baiju

Original Post Code:

```
string outPut = "0";
if (MyValue.ToString().Split('.').Length == 2)
{
outPut = MyValue.ToString().Split('.')[1].Substring(0, MyValue.ToString().Split('.')[1].Length);
}
Console.WriteLine(outPut);
```

Modified to your requirements:

```
decimal d = 44.22m;
string outPut = "0";
if (d.ToString().Split('.').Length == 2)
{
    outPut = d.ToString().Split('.')[1].Substring(0, d.ToString().Split('.')[1].Length);
}
Console.WriteLine(outPut);
```

> --input samples--
>   1) 46.0
>   2) 46.01
>   3) 46.000001
>   4) 46.1 
>   5) 46.12
>   6) 46.123
>   7) 46.1234
>
> --outputs--
>   1) 0
>   2) 01
>   3) 000001
>   4) 1
>   5) 12
>   6) 123
>   7) 1234